# How to change my networkstream code to write the data directly to file

Tags: c#, filestream, networkstream

my code is:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
MemoryStream receivedData = new MemoryStream();
do
{
numberOfBytesRead = serverStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //Read from network stream
receivedData.Write(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead); //Write to memory stream
Thread.Sleep(1);
} while (serverStream.DataAvailable);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\file.png", receivedData.ToArray());
```

I want convert it from MemoryStream to FileStream and i don't know.

and why i must use `Thread.Sleep(1)` to complete receiving bytes of file. Is there any correct statement instead of Sleep.

very thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  The conversion from MemoryStream to FileStream is straight-forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code using FileStream :

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\file.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    do
    {
        numberOfBytesRead = serverStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //Read from network stream
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
    } while (serverStream.DataAvailable);
    fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is very simple, and I am assuming that you are having trouble with how to open the file.  The `File` class provides a lot of useful utility methods in addition to the last one that you use, like [`File.OpenWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx):

```
FileStream receivedData = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\file.png");
```

As for the `Thread.Sleep(1)`--unless I am missing something not shown here--it looks like a chance to let the processor rest but it's rather pointless.  In particular, the `Read` call is IO bound waiting on the socket (network) to provide input so the entire loop is unlikely to be worthy of needing to sleep. *Most* calls to `Thread.Sleep` are hackish in nature.

Comment: thank you pickypg. i don't understand your last line comments: "Most calls to Thread.Sleep are hackish in nature". excuse me

Comment: There are very few valid uses for `Thread.Sleep` except in tight, _processor_ intensive loops that need to forcibly slow themselves down to avoid running CPU at max utilization (processor intensive loops are the way that you increase CPU utilization as they do not take breaks by definition except when the scheduler determines that they should/must). I have found that most calls to `Thread.Sleep` are not necessary and only serve to slow down things that are naturally blocking anyway, or that have no need to be slowed down. Ask yourself: why would you want to stop processing?